# Need help on Validating Response Method

Tags: citrus-framework

I have the response method which i need to validate, So i  have included the Conditional Statement, But however i am getting the script error as "Type mismatch: cannot convert from HttpClientResponseActionBuilder to boolean",

```
    if(http()
            .client(todoClient)
            .receive()
            .response(HttpStatus.OK).validate("$.statusCode", "200")) {
            For Report Purpose
      }
    else {
        For Report Purpose
    }
```

Is there a better way to achive what i am looking for.

Regards
BJ

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not compile because http() Java fluent API is not returning a `boolean` value here. So you can not place that in an `if` statement here.

You could make use of `conditional` test action containers instead. I am thinking of saving the Http status response code to a test variable. You can then use several conditional containers based on that response code value.

```
http().client(todoClient)
        .receive()
        .response()
        .extractFromHeader(HttpMessageHeaders.HTTP_STATUS_CODE, "statusCode");

conditional()
    .when("${statusCode} = 200")
    .actions(echo("Everything OK!"));

conditional()
    .when("${statusCode} = 404")
    .actions(echo("NOT FOUND!"));
```